# Set baseline with fontforge scriping

Tags: typography, fontforge

I'm using FontForge to create a ttf font from SVG files. But the baseline is all wrong and I can't understand how to set the baseline from the FontForge command line scriping tool.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The baseline is where y = '0' in the cartesian grid system of the 'em square'. If you look at the emsize, its likely 1,000, and typically there are 200 units below the baseline and 800 units above.

You can move the glyphs so that their base point is on the baseline, ie, their point has a y value of 0

Comment: Could you describe how exactly glyphs should be "moved"? In terms of fontforge preferably.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FF's python module, you'd do something like this to translate a single glyph:

```
import fontforge
import psMat
base_matrix = psMat.translate(0, 200)
# …
glyph.importOutlines(some_svg_file_object)
glyph.transform(base_matrix)
```